# Array outputs elements in a strange order

Tags: php, arrays

Using PHP 5.4.7 in a xampp dev environment.

I have a function in my data-layer file that fetches data from a MySql table, then creates a 2-dimensional array so that I can access the contents later. When I print out the elements in this data-layer file itself, using print_r, they print in the right order of indices, i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. But when I call this function elsewhere and print the elements, they come out in the order 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

The switch definitely happens between the time the function is created and the time it gets used. I've searched all over but not found anything like this mentioned on forums.

This is the function:

```
function getAllActivitiesAtEvent($eventId)
{
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM activity WHERE '$eventId' = activity.event_id");
    $result = @mysql_query ( $query ) or die ( mysql_error () );
    $num = mysql_num_rows ( $result );
    if ($num != 0)
    {
        $allActs[$num-1] = array();
        $i = 0;
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $result ) ) 
        {
            $oneAct = [ 
            "index" => $i,
            "actId" => $row ['activity_id'], 
            "actName" => $row ['activity_name'], 
            "actSC" => $row ['activity_short_code'], 
            "actPL" => $row ['project_leader'],
            "actCap" => $row ['capacity'], 
            "actDOW" => $row ['day_of_week'], 
            "actDate" => $row ['date']
            ];
            $allActs[$i] = $oneAct;
            $i++;
        }$i = 1;
    }
    return $allActs;
}
```

... and when i print_r on this page, the order is correct.

When I call this function on another page, like this:

```
dbconnect();
$activityArr = getAllActivitiesAtEvent($eventId);
```

and then print out the elements, the order is wrong!

Comment: Yes, show your code, please, it's hard to guess.

Comment: What's the question?  PHP will output the elements in the order they're assigned.  If the index 5 gets assigned before 2, then 5 will be displayed before 2 in print_r.
If you'd like them to be in numerical order, consider using [ksort](http://us1.php.net/ksort).

Comment: sorry, but i can't seem to figure out how to indent my code to make it look like code!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
function getAllActivitiesAtEvent($eventId)
{
    $query = ("SELECT * FROM activity WHERE '$eventId' = activity.event_id");
    $result = @mysql_query ( $query ) or die ( mysql_error () );
    $num = mysql_num_rows ( $result );
    $allActs = array();
    if ($num != 0)
    {
        $i = 0;
        while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $result ) ) 
        {
            $allActs[] = ["index" => $i++,
            "actId" => $row ['activity_id'], 
            "actName" => $row ['activity_name'], 
            "actSC" => $row ['activity_short_code'], 
            "actPL" => $row ['project_leader'],
            "actCap" => $row ['capacity'], 
            "actDOW" => $row ['day_of_week'], 
            "actDate" => $row ['date']];
        }
    }
    return $allActs;
}
```

The line $allActs[] = $oneAct will append them in order, $i is not really needed.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that and it does work, except that the ordering remains wonky! How do I attach a screen shot that shows what it does? In my database the 6 elements have the id numbers 93, 94, 95, 96, 97 and 98 but what gets output is always 98, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97.

Comment: If you add ORDER BY 'event_id' to the query, the order is still wonky?

Comment: @user2136826: i tried ORDER BY (on the activity_id column) and that didn't change the order on the calling page. Remember that on the function page (where it is declared), everything is in the right order. It's only on the calling page that the output is wonky. I'll try later with some of the other functions you've suggested here ...

Comment: Hi @eried, Sorry, I was a doofus and did not notice that you had taken out the name of my inner array - and as you can read below, that seems to solve the problem! Thank you so much. It's been a good learning experience for me.

Comment: So by the way, your solution, slightly different from user2190704's, works perfectly as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but I cleaned up the code a bit and added an 'ORDER BY' to your SQL statement.  I also used array() to add new $allAccts elements.  If you're just concerned about activity_id, you can do without the 'index' property and the $i counter.

If that still doesn't work, you might want to look into array_push (append elements) or array_unshift (prepend elements).  That's how you can safely implement LIFO or FIFO.

```
function getAllActivitiesAtEvent($eventId)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM activity WHERE event_id='".$eventId."' ORDER BY activity_id";
    $result = @mysql_query( $query ) or die ( mysql_error () );
    $allActs = array();
    if(mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0)
    {
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) )
        {
            $allActs[] = array( 
            "actId" => $row['activity_id'],
            "actName" => $row['activity_name'],
            "actSC" => $row['activity_short_code'],
            "actPL" => $row['project_leader'],
            "actCap" => $row['capacity'],
            "actDOW" => $row['day_of_week'],
            "actDate" => $row['date']);
        }
    }
    return $allActs;
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks. I only added that $i to the array because I wanted to print to screen something more meaningful to users than the activity_id from the db, and it made more sense for them to see 1,2,3 than 93, 94, 95 etc. But I can live without it. It's a detail.

Comment: Hey, this is fantastic! Your "cleaned up" version works perfectly! I see that explicitly naming that inner array was not necessary, which was a surprise to me. Also, can you perhaps explain why you quoted my $query that way? Other examples I've seen use parentheses. Could that have broken it, or is it more likely to have been the array within the array? Anyway, thanks very much indeed.

Comment: You're welcome!  I removed the parentheses around your query for aesthetic purposes; normally it's used for organizational or logic grouping.  In this query, I didn't think it was needed.  As for the broken code, I believe it was either the query's missing 'ORDER BY' or the inner array that wasn't ordered correctly.